# finding the kth shortest interval containing an integer

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, intervals

I am challenged with the following problem: I need to write a program that takes as input `n` intervals `[a,b]`, and `m` pairs `(k,d)`. For each `(k,d)` pair, the program should output the length of the kth shortest interval (where the length of an interval is defined as `b - a + 1`) where `a <= d <= b`. If `d` is not within any interval, or `d` is within less than `k` intervals, the program should output `-1`.

Example input/output:

[image]

The first integer (`5`) represents `n`. The next `n` lines contain intervals (so [2..4], [2..6], etc). Following is the integer `m` (`3`), followed by `m` lines of pairs `(k,d)`.

I am looking for an algorithm that solves this problem as quickly as possible.

Comment: You talk about `n` intervals and `m` pairs, but don't describe how the input is organized. For example, is `n` the first number in the file? Is this followed by `n` intervals [that we read in two numbers each]?. And, then, would we read the number `m` and then `m` pairs [two numbers each]? Or, are `n` and `m` the first two numbers in the file [respectively]. What is the description of the desired output. You show the output, but don't describe what (e.g.) `3`, `18`, and `-1` represent [exactly] Based on the file data, I'd _guess_ that `n` is `5` and `m` is `3`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Excuse me, I forgot to mention. I am looking for an algorithm to solve this within the smallest time complexity possible.

Comment: @CraigEstey I was indeed unclear about the input & the about, thank you for mentioning it. I've updated the question. Your assumptions about the input are correct. The output is the length of the kth smallest interval that contains d.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  We will help you fix problems with an honest attempt to solve the task, but we don't normally write the code for you.  Note that you should show the code you've tried and explain the problems you're encountering.  It should be an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.

Comment: You say: "_shortest_ interval". But, for the `[2,8]` pair, it matches intervals `[8,16]` and `2,19]` The first is of length 9 and the second is of length 19 (you're using `(b - a) + 1` [inclusive]). So, in your sample output, 18 is an "off-by-one" [from 19]. And the _shortest_ matching interval is `[8,16]` with length 9. So, unless I'm missing something, the desired output can't match the input.

Comment: @CraigEstey: The title says "kth shortest interval"; the question text says just "shortest interval".  I think that's simply a variation on the theme of 'typo' — the 'kth' got missed in the body of the question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Okay, I see that--thanks. And, although the sample program I wrote got the interval correct, I misread it when I talked about the off-by-one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved in O((*n* + *m*) log *n*) time with a [sweep line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm).

Sweep line algorithms set up a list of timed events and then process it in sorted order. For this problem, each interval [*a*, *b*] gives rise to a start event at time *a* and a stop event at time *b*. Each query (*k*, *d*) gives rise to a query event at time *d*. Since the intervals are fully closed, at each time, we process start events, then query events, then stop events.

We maintain a sorted list of the interval lengths stabbed by the sweep point. To process a start event, add the length of the interval to the list. To process a stop event, remove the length of the interval from the list. To process a query event, retrieve the *k*<sup>th</sup> element of the list. A sorted list data structure that supports all of these operations in O(log *n*) time is a red-black tree where each node contains the number of nodes in its left subtree. This is pretty much the canonical example of a tree augmentation, so CLRS and many other sources should have details.